# Codeception + Reusable utility helper functions

Tags: codeception

I'd like to reuse a function that retrieves some info from the database. I am able to add it in the Helper class that Codeception builds and it works, but it feels like I may not be putting this function in the proper place because Codeception "reads" it out in the list of steps.

I want to have something like

```
$price = $I->getProductPriceFromDatabase($productIdentifier,$arg2,$arg3);
```

in the steps. This works but I end up with

```
I get product price from db 13,4,19,9,1
```

in the output. Is there a better way to set up this helper function so that it is not part of the "output"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods of `$I` are steps and so they are printed in the steps output.

The only way to hide helper function is to call it from another helper function which looks better in the steps output.